# SSRS parameter usage in where clause

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hi I have one column HOLDJOB in SQL table. There are two values for this 1 or 0. I need to show in the SSRS report of onHold parameter is true then exclude the results with `ONHOLD ='1'`. If it is false. then report should show all results with onhold 1 or 0

Thanks in advance

I have put `AND p6.HOLDJOB =@OnHold` this filter in the query. And on the report I have defined parameter like `IF Yes='0'`. This is working fine. How can show all records when selection is No. I mean I have to exclude this condition

Comment: Is the parameter `@OnHold` a boolean or integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd format your `WHERE` clause with the following syntax.

```
SELECT 
    p6.* 
FROM 
    YourTable AS p6
WHERE
    1=1
    AND (@OnHold = 0 OR p6.HOLDJOB = @OnHold)
```